# Fetching multiple rows into single collection object - Laravel 4

Tags: optimization, laravel, laravel-4

Here is how my controller function looks like:

```
public function index()
{
        $fixtures = Fixture::with('homeTeam', 'awayTeam')->get();
    $homeTeams=$fixtures->fetch('home_team');
    $awayTeams=$fixtures->fetch('away_team');
    return View::make('fixtures',array('home'=>$homeTeams,'away'=>$awayTeams));
}
```

My aim is to print teams in the view as:

```
Home      -      Away
India     -      Australia
Sri Lanka -      England
and so on......
```

In my View I have:

```
@foreach($home as $homeT)
    <li>{{$homeT->tname}}</li>
@endforeach
```

which throws an error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

while if I use following to see what `$homeT` contains:

```
@foreach($home as $homeT)
    <li>{{$homeT}}</li>
@endforeach
```

I get following error:

> Array to string conversion

My question(s):
What is the best way to send both rows (homeTeam and awayTeams) to the view and print them as I've mentioned above?

### Edit1

Above foreach loop prints homeTeams properly if I use:

```
<li> {{$homeT['tname'] </li>
```

### Edit2

the database structure (required part of it)

```
//Table Name : team
tid               PK
team_name         (varchar)
tname             (varchar)
team_details      (varchar)


//Table Name : fixture
fid               PK
rid               FK
lid               FK
home_team_id      FK   |_ both referenced to 'tid' from 'team' table
away_team_id      FK   |
date
venue
```

here is the model : **Fixture.php**

```
class Fixture extends Eloquent {
    protected $table='fixture';
    protected $primaryKey = 'fid';

    public function homeTeam()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Team','home_team_id');
    }

    public function awayTeam()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Team','away_team_id');
    }
}
```

Thus, on applying @hayhorse's solution below, I get whole lot of unwanted data, viz, id's and venue etc etc.
It'd be great if that could be avoided and only the team names could be fetched, otherwise so much of unwanted data has to be sent to the view.

Comment: I'm guessing `$home` and `$away` are not incorrectly set in your real code? (Your code example should be passing `$homeTeams` and `$awayTeams` instead of `$home` and `$away` into the `fixtures` view, unless there's some code being omitted).

Comment: Additionally, doesn't the fact that `{{$homeT['tname']}}` works correctly just mean you're passing in an array of arrays instead of a collection of object? Why wouldn't you use `{{$homeT['tname']}}` if that's what works?

Comment: @fideloper yes, it works, I wanted to know If its possible to fetch both the rows together and access them in the view as:
`{{$fixture->homeTeam->tName}}-{{$fixture->awayTeam->tName}}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

controller

```
public function index()
{
    $fixtures = Fixture::with('homeTeam', 'awayTeam')->get();

    return View::make('fixtures', array('fixtures'=>$fixtures));
}
```

view

```
@foreach($fixtures as $fixture)
    <li>{{ $fixture->homeTeam->tname }} - {{ $fixture->awayTeam->tname }}</li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Vineetrok, this is the right answer. You might want to consider accepting it?

Comment: yeah, seems so, I didn't get a chance to try it out actually due to some problems. I shall accept is soon.

Comment: Well, I tried above method, and it did work. Although, there is a performance Issue I might have. I have described it in the latest edit of the question. Nevertheless, this answer is correct, But I shall like to see if there is way to optimize it further.

Comment: I doubt that the kind of micro-optimization you describe in your update will have any real effect on the efficiency of your site.

Answer (score 0):

Missing a `$` here before homeT:

```
@foreach($home as $homeT)
    <li>{{homeT->tname}}</li>
@endforeach
```

should be

```
@foreach($home as $homeT)
    <li>{{$homeT->tname}}</li>
@endforeach
```